# Where to get Mono support?

Tags: mono

It seems to me that with the release of MonoTouch and Mono for Android Mono has gotten a lot more attention and the quality of the Mono runtime has increased significantly through these products offered by Xamarin.

But as it looks Xamarin is only focused on "mobile development" and not on classic Linux development or embedded Linux development. Are there any other companies which offer (commercial) support in this area?

I am a little bit worried because we are planing to develop a large product based on embedded Linux and Mono. Where can I find support if there are any problems?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Support Isn't this page enough?

Comment: Well, I contacted Xamarin a while ago but didn't get any reply. Furthermore it looks to me that forums and Stackoverflow aren't a big help for mono development

Answer (score 0):

You should speak to Xamarin. They do offer commercial support for Mono, as per the Mono website:

[Commercial Support](http://www.mono-project.com/Support#Commercial_Support)

Additionally, you could try talking with [Lanedo](http://www.lanedo.com/services/)

Comment: I contacted Xamarin a while ago but didn't get any reply :(

Comment: @ollifant That's a shame. Definitely try to speak to Lanedo.

Answer (score 0):

[Miguel de Icaza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Icaza) has stated recently in various interviews and e-mails in mailing list that Xamarin are not offering consulting services outside the Mobile space.

However, Mono is open source, and as such, doesn't have any vendor lock-in. Virtually any opensource-based consulting firm could offer support contracts.

But I guess you want to know people who already have experience in supporting this software stack. Then, you have some particular alternatives:

- Sinenomine. This company has been mentioned several times by Miguel de Icaza.
- Lanedo. As mentioned by @TheNextMan, this company has done some consulting work for Xamarin too.
- Any freelance individual. From time to time, companies requiring consulting just post to the mono mailing list, and they get contacted by potential mono contributors to do work on a contractual basis (an example: me).